# Spyder Not launching on Anaconda navigator

Tags: python, tensorflow, spyder

Spyder was working until yesterday and now suddenly crushed and refuses to get launched from my environnement, it is still working on the root

error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/envs/PFE/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3181, in main
mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/envs/PFE/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3055, in run_spyder
main = MainWindow(options)
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/envs/PFE/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 353, in **init**
from spyder.plugins.configdialog import (MainConfigPage,
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/envs/PFE/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/plugins/configdialog.py", line 42, in 
from spyder.widgets.sourcecode.codeeditor import CodeEditor
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/envs/PFE/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/widgets/sourcecode/codeeditor.py", line 59, in 
from spyder.widgets.sourcecode.base import TextEditBaseWidget
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/envs/PFE/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/widgets/sourcecode/base.py", line 35, in 
from spyder.widgets.mixins import BaseEditMixin
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/envs/PFE/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/widgets/mixins.py", line 15, in 
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/envs/PFE/lib/python3.5/xml/sax/saxutils.py", line 6, in 
import os, urllib.parse, urllib.request
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/envs/PFE/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1, in 
import tensorflow as tf
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/envs/PFE/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 28, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow # pylint: disable=unused-import
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/envs/PFE/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 81, in 
from tensorflow.python import keras
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/envs/PFE/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/**init**.py", line 24, in 
from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/envs/PFE/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/activations.py", line 24, in 
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils import deserialize_keras_object
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/envs/PFE/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/**init**.py", line 21, in 
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils import GeneratorEnqueuer
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/envs/PFE/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 40, in 
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen
ImportError: cannot import name 'urlopen'

Comment: It is saying ```ImportError: cannot import name 'urlopen'``` Do you want to try to install ```urlopen``` into your environment?

Comment: Should i try to install it ? Because i don't remember installing it

Comment: Yes, please try to install it first and try again

Comment: Install it to your environment

Comment: nothing, still having the same problem, i think it is because of a code i executed before but how can resolve this problem ?

Comment: Does it still give the same error?

Comment: Yees i looked for how to install urlopen  (conda install -c anaconda urllib3) and i install it and still not working

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. Maybe you may want to reinstall anaconda altogether unless a better answer comes from the forum

Comment: Thank you anyway i'll keep looking